# Integrating in existing Android app, getting error null is not an object ( evaluating 'RNGestureHandlerModule.Direction)

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to integrate React Native in an existing Native App. I have been successful in integrating with iOS using CocoaPods and react native link. For Android I am getting the following error : -

```
null is not an object ( evaluating 'RNGestureHandlerModule.Direction)
```

I am following the FB tutorial for Android [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps)

my package.json dependencies section : -

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-native": "^0.59.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.5.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1"
  }
```

I have linked the RNGH following the guide [here](https://kmagiera.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/getting-started.html). I think the solution is the same as [the comment here](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/494#issuecomment-471164413). But in FBs guide to integrate with existing Native App, they don't have a guide with how to integrate with libraries that have native code.

**ReactMainActivity.java**

```
public class ReactMainActivity extends Activity implements DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler {
    private ReactRootView mReactRootView;
    private ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager;
    private final int OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE = 10;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mReactRootView = new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(this);
        mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
                .setApplication(getApplication())
                .setCurrentActivity(this)
                .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
                .setJSMainModulePath("index")
                .setDefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler(this)
                .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
                .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
                .build();
        // The string here (e.g. "MyReactNativeApp") has to match the
        // string in AppRegistry.registerComponent() in index.js
        mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager,
                "ReactApp", null);

        setContentView(mReactRootView);

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                        Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                startActivityForResult(intent, OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
            mReactInstanceManager.onHostPause(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
            mReactInstanceManager.onHostResume(this, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
            mReactInstanceManager.onHostDestroy(this);
        }
        if (mReactRootView != null) {
            mReactRootView.unmountReactApplication();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
            mReactInstanceManager.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU && mReactInstanceManager != null) {
            mReactInstanceManager.showDevOptionsDialog();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please enable System overlay display from settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
        mReactInstanceManager.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

**Application.java**

```
public class App extends MultiDexApplication implements ReactApplication {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SoLoader.init(this, false);
    }

    @Override
    public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
        return new ReactNativeHost(this) {
            @Override
            public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
                return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
            }

            @Override
            protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
                return Arrays.asList(new MainReactPackage(), new RNGestureHandlerPackage());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The problem as I can determine is my `Application::getReactNativeHost()` in the Application class implementing `ReactNativeApplication`, never gets triggered and hence I believe the native linking is failing.

Any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of a problem with version 3.+ I recommend using version 2.18.2

Steps to `downgrade`:

```
npm uninstall react-navigation

npm install react-navigation@2.18.2 --save
```

Start package:

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

Running the app:

```
react-native run-android
```